# Migrating to OAuth 2.0 login (OpenID Connect) from OpenID 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, openid

We are trying to migrate to OAuth 2.0 login (OpenID Connect) from OpenID 2.0

We are proceeding by [google docs OpenID 2.0 (Migration)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect)

The problem which we have is that **openid_id** is **not returned** in the ID token request.

First authentication request:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=openid+email&redirect_uri=http://domain.local/customer/auth-callback&openid.realm=http://domain.local/customer&state=secrettoken
```

When user is redirected back we get following params:

```
'state' => 'secrettoken',
'code' => 'codeforexchange',
'authuser' => '0',
'num_sessions' => '1',
'session_state' => 'absasd951d57fcc1148f59b6b455ec86045a731c..1de3',
'prompt' => 'none',
```

Then we exchange a token on `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` and we receive following:

```
'access_token' => 'accesstoken',
'token_type' => 'Bearer',
'expires_in' => 3594,
'id_token' => 'idtoken'
```

When we try to resolve token info on `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo` neither **openid_id** or sum is present as described in [docs - Step 3: Map OpenID 2.0 identifiers to OpenID Connect identifiers](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#map-identifiers)

Response is just (ID token):

```
 "issuer": "accounts.google.com",
 "issued_to": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "user_id": "user_id",
 "expires_in": 3594,
 "issued_at": 1404741485,
 "email": "someone@google.com",
 "email_verified": true
```

Anybody knows why?

Note: This "domain.local" was used previously to login via OpenId 2.0 so I expect that openid_id should be returned (to be able to migrate users identifiers from openid 2.0 to OpenidConnect)

There are similar questions which unfortunately does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

After getting id_token, you have to decode it to find openid_id. https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo does not return openid_id in response whether openid_id is included in encoded request data or not. For verification you can decode your id_token here; https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jwtdecoder

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will test this way.

Comment: If only i found this issue half day ago :/ Google tricked me too, giving this wrong response.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)  The sub is contained in the ID Token. I assume the openid_id is in there too.

> The ID Token is a security token that contains Claims about the
>   Authentication of an End-User by an Authorization Server when using a
>   Client, and potentially other requested Claims. The ID Token is
>   represented as a JSON Web Token (JWT) [JWT].

Comment: Unfortunately it's not, as you can see in our question - we've provided the id_token (I've updated my question to be more clear). I guess it's a bug.. :-/

Comment: Damn. You've probably already looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842475/migrating-google-openid-to-openid-connect-openid-id-does-not-match?rq=1), but if not it may help