# Google openid different when openid2.0 login to google-plus login?

Tags: google-plus, openid, google-oauth, google-openid

Currently I log users in with google using OpenID2.0 and I store the user's openID in the db table in the User model.

After upgrading to google-plus signin I obviously need to match up my existing users, so they are not prompted to register but rather are signed in.

I want to match them up by openid as google suggests doing in the migration guide.

To this end, I pass the openid realm param during google-plus signin, grab the `id_token` from google, decode it to get the openid of the user, then check for an existing user in my db with this openid. If they exist then great they can be logged in, if not then the site assumes they are a new user...

The problem is when I test this with an existing user, the openid I get from google during the google-plus signin flow seems to differ from the old openid I have stored in the database (that I got and stored from the openID2.0 signin flow) for the same user

Why is the openid different in these two flows?

(I am passing the same openid realm param each time)

Answer (score 3):

The openid_id value obtained through [step 3 of Google's migration documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#map-identifiers) should match the OpenID identifier value you were getting in your OpenID2 implementation.

If this is not the case, the most likely reason is that you are using a different openid.realm value in your OpenID Connect authorization request.

When constructing the OpenID Connect authentication request, make sure to use the same openid.realm value as you used in your OpenID 2.0 requests (as per [step 1.3 of Google's migration documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#adjust-uri)). Note that OpenID 2.0 identifiers are [directed](https://willnorris.com/2009/07/openid-directed-identity-identifier-select), ie, users have different identifiers across different relaying parties (RPs), since OpenID 2.0 does not provide a registration process, the openid.realm value is used to identify RPs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but yeah, I am passing the same openid realm, and they still seem to be different...hmmph...

Comment: _exactly_ the same realms? That's odd. You sure you are using the "openid_id" value in the ID Token instead of the "sub" one? (the former is the OpenID2 identifier, the latter the OpenID Connect identifier).

Comment: hmm, hopefully I'm using the open_id value from the id_token, but I'm not 100% sure.  Once I have the id_token from google, I do (python) `from oauth2client.client import verify_id_token; jwt = verify_id_token(id_token, settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID); openid_id = jwt.get('openid_id', None)` to decode the openid_id...so I presume this must be correct because I'm grabbing the 'openid_id' key not the 'sub' key.

Comment: As for exactly the same, the only possible difference I could envisage it that some users signed up through http rather than https, but it seems rather unlikely

Comment: Here are the requests, one when I roll back to the branch using openid2.0, and the next for the google-plus branch: http://paste.ofcode.org/Bnym72tNL9VuPcEt5ttzRD

Comment: They are just on the local dev server, and I get different openids returned each time for the same user login. The only difference I can see is the trailing slash...surely not that?

Comment: Hmm I tried it, and it now seems to give matching openids....so it's sensitive down to a trailing slash??

Comment: A trailing slash leads to a no-match, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842475/migrating-google-openid-to-openid-connect-openid-id-does-not-match/23051643#23051643.

Glad to hear the problem is solved though.